# Database creation and double checking for mistakes

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datagrip

I created a database in one of my project but I'm not sure if I still doing it right. I'm still learning sql and I stuggle in some of the tables I make. The operations are the following.

1. I can add officer with it's assign division.
2. I have to check every division what their plan and their corresponding items with milestone(months) each year.
3. I can also check how many items per milestone(months) & vice Versa.

Tables are **officer**, **division**, **plan**, **items**, **milestone**, when I try to create this table in http://sqlfiddle.com I got an error of **Can't create database 'db_9_85e4c'; database exists** when I try to alter and create a foreign key in **officer & division table**.

Here's my tables:

Officer Table

```
create table officer
(
    id int not null auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    s_position varchar(50) null,
    f_position varchar(100) not null,
    constraint officer_name_uindex
        unique (name),
    constraint officer_position_uindex
        unique (f_position),
    constraint officer_division_division_id_fk
        foreign key (id) references test.division (division_id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
)
;
```

Division Table

```
    create table division
(
    division_id int not null
        primary key,
    acronym varchar(50) not null,
    sequence_id int not null,
    decription varchar(50) not null,
    constraint division_sequesnce_id_uindex
        unique (sequence_id),
    constraint division_acronym_uindex
        unique (acronym),
    constraint division_decription_uindex
        unique (decription),
    constraint division_ppmp_ppmp_id_fk
        foreign key (division_id) references test.ppmp (ppmp_id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
)
;
```

Plan Table

```
create table ppmp
(
    ppmp_id int not null auto_increment
        primary key,
    year varchar(50) not null
)
;
```

Items Table

```
create table items
(
    id int not null auto_increment
        primary key,
    description varchar(100) not null,
    unit varchar(50) not null,
    quantity int not null,
    budget double not null,
    mode varchar(50) not null,
    constraint items_milestone_id_fk
        foreign key (id) references test.milestone (id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint items_ppmp_ppmp_id_fk
        foreign key (id) references test.ppmp (ppmp_id)
            on update cascade on delete cascade
)
;
```

Milestone Table

```
create table milestone
(
    id int not null auto_increment
        primary key,
    january int null,
    february int null,
    march int null,
    april int null,
    may int null,
    june int null,
    july int null,
    august int null,
    september int null,
    october int null,
    november int null,
    decemeber int null
)
;
```

[image: plan]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the schema with the tables in this order

- Milestone
- ppmp
- items
- division
- officer

the problem is happening because Officer have a foreing key to division_id but that table and column does not exists yet.

Comment: I tried this one create **officer**  first then I created **division** tables then lastly I **alter**  officer table to create a foreign key to division table.